# Vue 2 v-for multiple orderby

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I need help ordering an array with key: 'updated_at' and "order_at, right now the code searches and reverses, but I can't get it to orderby, you can see a jsfiddle here: can any one help me please, here is part of the due code

Appreciate any help

```
    data: {
        items: array goes here,
        searchObj: {
            msgText: '',
            desc_en: '',
            created_at: '',
            updated_at: '',
            sort: false
        },
        sortKey: 'updated_at'
    },

    filters: {
        formatDate: function (date_data) {
            moment.locale('{{$user->lang}}');
            return moment(date_data).format('lll') + ' EST';
        }
    },

    methods: {
        orderBy: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        itemsWithFilter: function () {
            var that = this;
            return that.items
            .filter(function (item) {
                if(item.desc_en) {
                    results = item.name_en.toLowerCase().indexOf(that.searchObj.msgText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                    results2 = item.desc_en.toLowerCase().indexOf(that.searchObj.msgText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                    return results + results2;
                }
            })
            .sort(function (a, b) {
                if (that.searchObj.sort)
                    return a[that.sortKey] > b[that.sortKey] ? 1 : -1;
                else
                    return a[that.sortKey] > b[that.sortKey] ? -1 : 1;
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your radio buttons to model `sortKey`, so that when you pick a radio button, `messagesWithFilter` is recomputed.

```
<input type="radio" name="orderBy" v-model="sortKey" id="normal" value="message" checked="checked"><label for="normal">orderBy normal (this should be auto selected on load)
<br>
<input type="radio" name="orderBy" v-model="sortKey" id="created_at" value="created_at"><label for="created_at">orderBy created_at
<br>
<input type="radio" name="orderBy" v-model="sortKey" id="updated_at" value="updated_at"><label for="updated_at">orderBy updated_at
```

Comment: Hi Roy thanks for the answer , it works, so easy with due... when you know

Comment: Roy one thing I notice is when <input type="radio" name="orderBy" v-model="sortKey" id="name_en" value="name_en" /> is selected it shows Z... A, instead or ascending A...m...z, is there any way to fix this one radio? the others ones are correct

Comment: Sort order depends on your sort function. You could do something like `if (that.searchObj.sort && that.sortKey !== 'message')...` so that message gets the reverse ordering.

Comment: Hi Roy, I tried your last code, but that only sorts when the .sort is call, the idea is that when sortKey == 'name_en' the list is descending, so I tried this but it doesn't do anything:

            itemsWithFilter: function () {
                var that = this;
             if (that.sortKey == 'name_en')
     return _.orderBy(that.items, 'name_en', 'asc');
                else
                 return that.items

Comment: Roy just one question, I was wondering if the image gets reloaded every time the sortKey changes? I feel theres a request to the server each time the order is changed